# Confusion over TCP FIN =1 flag and HTTP Session End

Tags: http, session, tcp

Ok, So I guess I got things the wrong way, does a HTTP session end with the arrival of FIN = 1 or is there something else going on that makes a client application know that there is no more data to receive? I am analyzing the network stream over the wire using WireShark, and at the moment, I am having trouble understanding this.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases you should see "Content-Length: ..." HTTP header telling you how much data (in bytes) follows after "\r\n\r\n" sequence. Said sequence marks end of headers and beginning HTTP message body.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection

Comment: But I dont understand the FIN flag, does this mean FIN does not come into action, so all control is under HTTP? Supposedly when we have a scenario of a webpage being downloaded by a browser, graphics from different links, how will the browser know everything is has been collected for the page. Could this be a browser controlled issue?

Comment: Browser sends requests for each resource it wants to assemble the page. Browser and server decide who and when closes connection. In HTTP version 1.1 it's done with headers "Connection: keep-alive" or "Connection: close". Normally server would try to keep connection open in anticipation of more requests (to save on TCP handshake when next image needs to be downloaded, for example).

Comment: OK, so this typicall means that when we have a Keep-Alive connection, the ip and porst (which I call a connection) would be the same in this  mode?

Comment: Yes. You can follow stream in Wireshark.